# App crash when editing comment or uploading image

Tags: bug, android-app

I've got a [Google Pixel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Pixel), the latest version of the Stack Exchange app, and here is the repro video:

> [image: video-gif]

Original Link to video gif: [http://imgur.com/QJO2Ypc](https://imgur.com/QJO2Ypc)

Also, when I tried to upload this GIF file to this question, again using my phone, choosing the GIF file from the device also crashes the app, hence the Imgur link.

I've edited comments on my phone before, so I know it works/worked. All of a sudden the app is crashing.

Comment: I cant reproduce this anymore, however I suspect the failure occurred when I tapped on the word `IOException` and since it was an unknown word it *tried* to bring up the Dictionary with the "auto-suggest context menu" and that caused an unhandled exception, it felt as if it could have been a second chance exception.

Comment: Your video link is broken.

Comment: No, it works. Its an animated gif on Imgur, I checked it works just then... Thats a good point though, gif formats aren't accepted on SE sites.

Comment: Seems imgur link can't be opened on iPad. Works on PC.

Comment: I knew Steve Jobs [hated Flash](http://www.apple.com/hotnews/thoughts-on-flash/) but GIF Images, c'mon Apple, no wonder I've gone Google!

Comment: @alexolut sounds like you're using Safari? Probably will work on Chrome, and anyway take a look [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/AlienBlue/comments/2wognn/gifs_dont_work_anymore_on_ipad/) (there's an advice "Switch to standard mode instead of optimal" maybe it will work for you too. :))

Comment: @ShadowWizard nope. Tried Chrome too. Possibly was a problem with mobile (`m.`) part of the *imgur*. Now it's works fine. Moreover imgur video is not an animated gif, it's a .mp4 video file.

Comment: It's back I am getting the exception again :(

Comment: The unhandled exception occurs when you touch a misspelled word when editing a comment using a Google Pixel, should be easy to repro @DavidFullerton