# App crashes editing a comment with spelling error

Tags: bug, android-app

[App crash when editing comment or uploading image](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287491/156316)

I added a bounty to the issue a while back, it still isn't fixed. Could you please look into this, thanks

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: Google
- Device Model: Pixel

  - OS Version: 7.1.1 (3636322)

Comment: Not yet fixed bug is not a good reason to make a dupe question. As far as I know developing around Android app is frozen. I didn't see any updates/fixes for months. Adding a bounty for bug/feature request also is not enough productive (I made sure personally in this).

Comment: I actually submitted via the phone app "Submit Bug" and it ended up posting here. Also I would have deleted it but there isn't an option to do that using the mobile app. Happy for this to have been closed as a duplicate, I know the rules.